# Error after saving and then editing a transaction in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, transactions, dataset, dataadapter

after successfully saving a transaction using my code...I edit the transaction and then save...then i come up with this error message:

> ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.

here is my code:

```
Try
  sqlTrans = sqlCon_.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead)
  sSQLAdapter_.UpdateBatchSize = 30
  sCommand_ = DirectCast(sSQLAdapter_.SelectCommand, SqlCommand)
  sCommand_.Connection = sqlCon_ 
  sCommand_.Transaction = sqlTrans 
  sSQLAdapter.SelectCommand.Transaction = sqlTrans

  sSQLAdapter_.Update(sDataSet.Tables(0))

  sqlTrans.Commit()
  sqlCon_.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
  sqlTrans.Rollback()
Finally
   sSQLAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection.Close()
   sSQLAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = Nothing
   sSQLAdapter.SelectCommand.Transaction = Nothing
   sSQLAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = ""
   sSQLAdapter.SelectCommand.Dispose()

   sqlTrans.Dispose()
   sqlCon_.Close()
   sqlCon_.Dispose()
End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set Transaction object reference for `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` object of SqlDataAdapter because you're calling `Update` method.

MSDN reference document - [Using Transactions with a DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971557.aspx)

Sample :

```
Using Cn As New SqlConnection(CnStr)
 Cn.Open()
 Using Trans As SqlTransaction = Cn.BeginTransaction
   Dim Adp As New SqlDataAdapter(selectQuery, Cn)
   Adp.SelectCommand.Transaction = Trans

   Dim cmb As New SqlCommandBuilder(Adp)
   Adp.DeleteCommand = cmb.GetDeleteCommand()
   Adp.InsertCommand = cmb.GetInsertCommand()
   Adp.UpdateCommand = cmb.GetUpdateCommand()

   Adp.InsertCommand.Transaction = Trans
   Adp.DeleteCommand.Transaction = Trans
   Adp.UpdateCommand.Transaction = Trans

   Dim dt As New DataTable
   Adp.Fill(dt)
   /* ------------- 

    Perform insert/delete/update on DataSet or DataTable 
    -------------- */ 
   Adp.Update(dt)
   Trans.Commit()
  End Using
 Cn.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: theres an error with this line... is it valid? sSQLAdapter_.UpdateCommand.Transaction = sqlTrans

Comment: You *should* generate InsertCommand, UpdateCommand, and DeleteCommand and you must set the Transaction property for each InsertCommand, UpdateCommand, and DeleteCommand. Use CommandBuilder to generate these three command objects.

Comment: I see...but sCommand_ is from sSQLAdapter_.SelectCommand...and sSQLAdapter is binded to object using dataset...

Comment: hi sir...thanks for your great sample..it works...but i get a little message...it says "Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records."... how to deal with that?

Comment: sorry for bothering...but the message still appears... "Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records."...i dont know what to do now.

Comment: Because in given sample I've used `The Saving-All-Values Approach` by generating `UpdateCommand` via `CommandBuilder`. In that case you've to configure `Command` objects [manually](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2010/04/07/concurrency-violation-the-updatecommand-affected-0-of-the-expected-1-records.aspx).